# Will "off-screen" ADBannerView count impressions?

Tags: ios, iad, off-screen, impressions

I'm maintaining a sole instance of ADBannerView (as the docs suggested), and present is at some points troughout the UX.

But I can see that bannerViewDidLoadAd: callbacks are keep invoked even if the banner is not presented.

That is really good on one hand (thatswhy I made this design), but I was wondering whether those loading will counted as impressions in some aggregated statistics? And that could affect my revenues in some unintended way.

Will it count? What is your experience?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** :)

Implicitaed in another error message that told me that "banner view is presented, but has no Ad loaded", or so. So it seems framework is tracking the visibility of banner views whatever happens. Which is... ...not too surprising at all, just wanted to be sure.